# Does the phrase “mug my day off” make sense?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

i heard “mug someone off” so i was wondering about “mug something off”. Have you ever heard someone say it? And if so what does it mean exactly?

Comment: Did you hear or read this sentence before?

Comment: no actually, but i read “mug someone off” so i was wondering about “mug something off”

Comment: You may fix your question and explain why you are asking.